# Is it possible to simplify these kinds of checks on dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary containing lists of dictionaries and nested lists of strings.
I figured out a way using comprehensions to perform checks before adding items.
However, I'm not sure if this is the best, most simplified way to do this.

```py
    my_dict = {
        'employees':[
            {
                'name':'Kevin',
                'software':[
                    {
                        'name':'soft1',
                        'modules':[
                            'mod1',
                            'mod2',
                            'mod3'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'name':'soft2', 
                        'modules':[
                            'mod1',
                            'mod2',
                            'mod3'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'name':'soft3', 
                        'modules':[
                            'mod1',
                            'mod2',
                            'mod3'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name':'Bob', 
                'software':[
                    {
                        'name':'soft3', 
                        'modules':[
                            'mod4',
                            'mod5',
                            'mod6'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'name':'soft4', 
                        'modules':[
                            'mod10'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'name':'soft6', 
                        'modules':[
                            'mod1',
                            'mod5'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'name':'soft7', 
                        'modules':[
                            'mod1',
                            'mod3',
                            'mod5'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    new_employee_name = "Steward"
    new_software_learnt = "soft2"
    new_module_learnt = "mod20"
    
    if not new_employee_name in [_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']]:
        my_dict['employees'].append({'name':new_employee_name, 'software':[{"name":new_software_learnt, 'modules':[new_module_learnt]}]})
        
    new_software_learnt = "soft3"
    new_module_learnt = "mod22"
    
    if not new_software_learnt in [_['name'] for _ in [_['software'] for _ in my_dict['employees']][[_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']].index(new_employee_name)]]:
        my_dict['employees'][[_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']].index(new_employee_name)]['software'].append({'name':new_software_learnt, 'modules':[new_module_learnt]})
    
    new_software_learnt = "soft3"
    new_module_learnt = "mod55"
    
    if not new_module_learnt in [_['modules'] for _ in [_['software'] for _ in my_dict['employees']][[_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']].index(new_employee_name)]][[_['name'] for _ in [_['software'] for _ in my_dict['employees']][[_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']].index(new_employee_name)]].index(new_software_learnt)]:
        [_['modules'] for _ in [_['software'] for _ in my_dict['employees']][[_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']].index(new_employee_name)]][[_['name'] for _ in [_['software'] for _ in my_dict['employees']][[_['name'] for _ in my_dict['employees']].index(new_employee_name)]].index(new_software_learnt)].append(new_module_learnt)
    
    print(my_dict['employees'])
```

Could anyone suggest a better more simplified approach?
Perhaps there are some modules that are good in that?
Should I better break down the comprehensions into separate functions to check each "level" of the dictionary?

Ultimately, this dictionary will be saved as json file.

Comment: Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, moving the work into one or more helper functions will simplify your mainline code significantly. `add_empdata()` should probably be refactored further, but here is a quick and dirty example of the general idea:

```
from pprint import pprint

def add_empdata(empdict, empname, swname, modname):
    # find employee record if extant else create new employee record and exit
    for employee in empdict["employees"]:
        if employee["name"] == empname:
            break
    else:  # no break
        empdict["employees"].append(dict(name=empname, software=[dict(name=swname, modules=[modname])]))
        return

    # add software and module data for extant employee if not already in employee
    for software in employee["software"]:
        if software["name"] == swname:
            if modname not in software["modules"]:
                software["modules"].append(modname)
            break
    else:  # no break
        employee["software"].append(dict(name=swname, modules=[modname]))

new_empdata = [
    ("Steward", "soft2", "mod20"),
    ("Steward", "soft3", "mod22"),
    ("Steward", "soft3", "mod55"),
]
for empname, swname, modname in new_empdata:
    add_empdata(my_dict, empname, swname, modname)

pprint(my_dict['employees'])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Kevin',
  'software': [{'modules': ['mod1', 'mod2', 'mod3'], 'name': 'soft1'},
               {'modules': ['mod1', 'mod2', 'mod3'], 'name': 'soft2'},
               {'modules': ['mod1', 'mod2', 'mod3'], 'name': 'soft3'}]},
 {'name': 'Bob',
  'software': [{'modules': ['mod4', 'mod5', 'mod6'], 'name': 'soft3'},
               {'modules': ['mod10'], 'name': 'soft4'},
               {'modules': ['mod1', 'mod5'], 'name': 'soft6'},
               {'modules': ['mod1', 'mod3', 'mod5'], 'name': 'soft7'}]},
 {'name': 'Steward',
  'software': [{'modules': ['mod20'], 'name': 'soft2'},
               {'modules': ['mod22', 'mod55'], 'name': 'soft3'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks @rhurwitz, so, your suggestion is to ditch the dictionary and list comprehensions and use standard for loops instead?

Comment: My example uses your current data structure, `my_dict`, as is, but moves the handling of it to functions. In general, list comprehensions make the most sense when you are building new collections, not just iterating over existing ones.

Comment: something doesn't quite work in the function above

Comment: I will be glad to take another look at it.  Can you be more specific regarding the issue you saw?  I used your `my_dict`, not shown in my example, as the input.

Comment: when modules and software are added it seem to append new dictionaries instead of appending modules and software

Comment: wait, I may be wrong here, can FOR have an ELSE? I may be assuming your indentation is wrong. I have never seen a FOR with ELSE :)

Comment: `for` and `while` statements can have `else` blocks in Python that are only executed if the loop is terminated without a `break`.  The feature is rarely needed, and even in this case would have been unnecessary had I taken the time to refactor the example.